# Create process with a series of irregular changes

Tags: list-manipulation, time-series, random

I want to create a process with a series of irregular changes. For example, imagine we have a list of day numbers: {10, 23, 37, 45, 62} and a list of changes of the same length: {-5, 7, 14, -3, 25} and a starting level of 9 and we wish to create a list of levels over the course of 90 days. So, the list is like:

{ 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,11,11,11,...}

In other words, the level goes down by 5 on day 10, then goes up by 7 on day 23, etc. How can I generate a list like this, given the parameters set out above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
process[start_,day_,change_]:=FoldList[Plus,start,Normal[SparseArray[day-1->change]]]

process[9,{10,23,37,45,62},{-5,7,14,-3,25}]
```

> {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,47}

---

#### Per the [comment's new requirement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133464/create-process-with-a-series-of-irregular-changes/133503#comment360174_133503) about a limit size:

```
process[start_, limitSize_, day_, change_] := 
 FoldList[Plus, start, 
  Normal[SparseArray[day - 1 -> change, limitSize - 1]]]

process[9, 90, {10, 23, 37, 45, 62}, {-5, 7, 14, -3, 25}]
```

> {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47}

Comment: That is ingenious.

Comment: The only problem is that there is no end day. So, for example, if you wanted a year's worth of data, you would need to specify 365 as the number of items in the result list, otherwise it works perfectly. So, for example, in my answer the end list size is hardcoded as 363.

Comment: I'm not very sure what you have said.Maybe this `process[start_,day_,change_]:=Module[{t},PadRight[t=FoldList[Plus,start,Normal[SparseArray[day-1->change]]],365,Last[t]]]`

Comment: This does it: process[start_, size_, day_List, change_List] := 
 FoldList[Plus, start, 
  Normal[SparseArray[day - 1 -> change, size - 1]]]

Comment: That is ingenious. :)

Comment: For avoid that error when your size less than 62,I have give a update for that just now.

Comment: You don't need `PadRight[]`: `FoldList[Plus, start, Normal[SparseArray[day - 1 -> change, LimitSize - 1]]]`.

Comment: BTW, it is not a "new" requirement. If you read the original question, it clearly indicates that there is a specific desired size to the list ("over the course of 90 days").

Answer (score 2):

```
day = {10, 23, 37, 45, 62};
change = {-5, 7, 14, -3, 25};
max = 90;
level = 9;

accu = {0}~Join~change // Accumulate
```

> {0, -5, 2, 16, 13, 38}

```
partitions = {1}~Join~day~Join~{max + 1} // Differences
```

> {9, 13, 14, 8, 17, 29}

```
p = Internal`PartitionRagged[ConstantArray[9, max], partitions]
```

> {{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
>     9}, {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
>     9, 9}, {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {9, 9, 
>     9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
>      9, 9, 9, 9}}

```
p + accu
```

> {{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
>     4}, {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}, {25, 
>     25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25}, {22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
>     22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22}, {47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 
>     47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 
>     47, 47, 47, 47}}

Comment: You might consider `FoldList[Plus, 9, {-5, 7, 14, -3, 25}]`. Then use `MapThread[]` with `partitions`.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually gave up and wrote this procedurally as follows (with a different set of data than in the original question):

```
dayChange = Sort[RandomSample[Range[1, 363], 60]];

changeAccumulated={132,135,125,137,138,136,135,134,136,126,115,121,134,130,131,131,130,129,120,124,129,141,155,155,158,147,137,137,139,142,142,143,143,134,127,135,137,138,147,146,156,161,168,177,179,188,178,168,173,183,185,197,197,196,185,176,171,176,176,177};

Module[  
   {xChange = 1},
   data = {};
   Do[
      If[x == 1,    
         AppendTo[data, 120],    
         If[xChange <= Length[dayChange] && dayChange[[xChange]] == x,
            (AppendTo[data, changeAccumulated[[xChange]]]; 
               xChange++),
               AppendTo[data, data[[x - 1]]]]],
      {x, 1, 363}]]
```

[image]

If anybody has a more elegant way to do this functionally, I am happy to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1):

Another take:

```
process[start_, limitSize_, day_, change_] /; Length@day == Length@change := 
 Join @@ MapThread[Table[#1, {#2}] &,
          {Accumulate[Prepend[change, start]], Differences@Join[{1}, day, {limitSize + 1}]}
         ]
```

Then,

```
process[9, 90, {10, 23, 37, 45, 62}, {-5, 7, 14, -3, 25}]
```

yields the same [answer as yode's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133503/29734).

Comment: `Table[#1, {#2}] &` can of course be replaced by `ConstantArray`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, but I prefer the more terse version. I imagine `ConstantArray` will be faster on larger lists.

Comment: As it turns out, in newer versions, `Table[n, k]` works and is entirely equivalent to `ConstantArray[n, k]`.

Comment: @J.M. I am unfortunately stuck on 10.0 (had to buy my own copy on an internal grant, so I can't upgrade) where that hasn't yet been implemented, but that would be my preferred version, for sure.